# Disable hover effect of nav toggle when nav menu is open

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to disable the hover effect of the navigation toggle button when the navigation menu is open. I'm toggling a class when the button is clicked and running an if statement that says it should only run the animation if the class isn't toggled. I can see in the console that div.toggle-btn is toggling the disable-hover class but it doesn't disable/enable the javascript code like I expect.

```
var btnhover = new TimelineMax({paused: true});

var navtoggle = $('.toggle-btn').hasClass('disable-hover');

if (navtoggle === false) {
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    btnhover.to(".one", .3, {
       y: 5,
       ease: Expo.easeInOut,
    })}
  else {
    btnhover.to(".one", .3, {
       x: -5,
       ease: Expo.easeInOut,
    })
  }
}

if (navtoggle === false) {
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    btnhover.to(".two", .3, {
       y: -5,
       ease: Expo.easeInOut,
       delay: -.3
    })}
  else {
    btnhover.to(".two", .3, {
       x: 5,
       ease: Expo.easeInOut,
       delay: -.3
    })
  }
}

function btnover(){
  if (navtoggle === false) {
    btnhover.play();
  }
}

function btnout(){
  if (navtoggle === false) {
    btnhover.reverse();
  }
}

$(".toggle-btn").hover(btnover, btnout);


function disableHover() {
  $("div.toggle-btn").toggleClass("disable-hover");
}

$(document).on("click", ".toggle-btn", function() {
      disableHover();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking if navToggle is false, I think you need to check for truthy value also